# Select records based on independent conditions in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

please find below the sample database:

```
CREATE TABLE ipay
    (Ticket int(11) Primary Key,Login int(11), Profit double, opentime datetime);

INSERT INTO ipay
(Ticket,Login,Profit,opentime)
VALUES
(1,100,100,'2020-01-01 00:00:00'),
(2,100,100,'2020-02-01 00:00:00'),
(3,100,-200,'2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
(4,100,-50,'2020-01-02 00:00:00'),
(5,101,200,'2020-02-02 00:00:00'),
(6,101,200,'2020-03-02 00:00:00'),
(7,101,-10,'2020-04-02 00:00:00'),
(8,101,-200,'2020-05-02 00:00:00')
```

When Profit> 0, you can think the record as a deposit; when Profit<0, you can think the record as a withdrawal.

I need to get all withdrawals that happened after the first deposit, for each individual login. So that the expected output would be:

| Ticket | Login | Profit | opentime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 100 | -50 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 7 | 101 | -10 | 2020-04-02 00:00:00 |
| 8 | 101 | -200 | 2020-05-02 00:00:00 |

(For login 100, Ticket 3 is filtered out as it was made before Ticket 1;
For login 101, both Ticket 7 and 8 are included, since both were made after Ticket 5)

I have managed to identify the time when the first deposit was made:

```
SELECT LOGIN, TICKET, PROFIT,  SUM(PROFIT), MIN(OPENTIME)
FROM ipay 
WHERE PROFIT>0
GROUP BY LOGIN
```

I am stuck as there are more than one MIN(opentime).

I'm currently using MySQL version 5.7.34. Please do not hesitate to let me know if any clarification is needed. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: Aren't *all* withdrawals after the first deposit? How can you withdraw money if there's no money in the account?!

Comment: @Bohemian, thanks for your comment. In the real world, people deposited via various methods but I only need to analyse one method. That means there are some other deposits that were made earlier but are irrelevant. Just assume I have filtered them out in the sample database.

Comment: Which column indicates what "method" was used?

Comment: @Bohemian, in the real-world database, there is another column called 'comment'. I can use the column to filter out irrelevant deposits easily. I just did not include it in the sample database for simplicity.

Comment: Or you could think every login had a beginning balance before the first deposit was made.

Comment: unless it’s an overdraft account, which allow negative balances, accounts are created with a zero balance and the only first transaction allowed is to make a deposit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this

```
select * from ipay as a left join 
    (select login,min(opentime) as firsttime 
     from ipay  where profit>0 
     group by login 
     order by opentime) as b 
on a.login=b.login 
where a.opentime>firsttime and profit<0
```

see in action here :[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e48494/18)

Comment: That's it! Can't believe I did not know it :) Thanks. @sama latifi